# how to stop the action until the internet is connect java

Tags: java

how can i wait to do the action until the connection is back

i have some code here 
this to open connection

```
public static  boolean checkconnection() {
    Socket sock=new Socket();
    InetSocketAddress addr=new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com",80);
    try {
        sock.connect(addr,3000);
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }finally {
        try {
            sock.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and this to do the action

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
     WebDriver dr;
     dr = new ChromeDriver();
    boolean con=checkconnection();
    int p=100;
    for(int i=0;i<p.size();i++){
if(con==true){
    try {
             dr.get("http://www.google.com/");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {continue;}
    }

    }else {
// here i wanna it to wait until the connect come back and resume the job 
not this message 
            //System.out.println("the internet connection is disconnect");
        }

    }
```

how can i wait or pause until the internet connect inside for loop 
i'm looking for resume the job back not to start again from the begin 
the thing that i'm looking for it to
wait until the connection comeback and resume the job from where it is stop or pause

Comment: Why do you think the socket is not connected? The java Socket is not asynchronous. Either it returns connected or a TimeoutException occurs. You may increase the timeout value. But im most cases: If the socket cannot connect within 3 seconds it probably will neither succeed in the next 10 seconds or so. Then something else is not goot which has to be fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can put your connection test in a while cycle. You can exit only if the connection is active.

```
private boolean flag=false; //true if the connection is active
while(!flag){
    try {
        dr.get("http://www.google.com/");
        //For loop "i" operations
        flag=true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        //flag=false;    
        //Your operations are canceled 
    }
}
//now you can go to the i+1 iteration of the for loop
```

EDIT: See the following code to understand what i want to say.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
   
   [...]
   
   private boolean flag=false; 
   int p=100;
   for(int i=0;i<p.size();i++){
    flag=false; //because we would like to check the connection every time
    while(!flag){
      try {
          dr.get("http://www.google.com/");
          System.out.println("The current iteration is "+i);
          flag=true;
      }catch(Exception e){
        //System.out.println("the internet connection is disconnect");
        //flag remains false;    
        /*The operations in the Try-block are canceled and
        now we can try again (the i in the for loop is the same)*/
      }//end catch
    }//end while
  }//end for
}//end main
```

Your output will be:

> The current iteration is 0
>
> The current iteration is 1
>
> The current iteration is 2
>
> The current iteration is 3
>
> The current iteration is 4
>
> [...]
>
> The current iteration is p.size-1
>
> The current iteration is p.size

even if you lose your connection, and not

> The current iteration is 0
>
> The current iteration is 1
>
> The current iteration is 2
>
> The current iteration is 3
>
> The current iteration is 4
>
> [...]
>
> The current iteration is N //now connection lost
>
> The current iteration is 0
>
> The current iteration is 1
>
> The current iteration is 2
>
> [...]

Comment: u didn't get me i mean when i inside the for loop and it work look at the code inside the for loop to clarify it i'm now inside the for while it working the internet get off what can i do to wait until it come back and return to fore loop again

Comment: Ok... It's the same thing: put my code in the for loop and the specific operations of the "i" iteration in the while loop. If the connection is lost, you'll try to repeat these operations and when the connection come back, the for loop starts from the i+1 iteration.

Comment: can u clarify it with me code so i can understand it

Comment: Of course! I've edited my answer and added some examples.

Comment: it go out from the loop if there is no internet connection i don't wanna it to go out i need it to wait until the internet back ans start work

Comment: No! If the connection Is lost, my code remains in the while loop and try to do the current operations (because flag remains false). Only if the connection returns and the operations are correctly executed (so flag=true), It Can exit from the while loop and proceed with the for loop (from the next iteration)... You'll never exit the for loop before i=p.size !!!